# An URL that is all parameters

Tags: taxonomy-terms, uri, views

I'm building a website related to videogames. There's a view that shows all videogames catalogued in the website, using taxonomy terms as arguments, that is:

mysite.com/games/genre/platform

The problem is that the "games" part in the URL is unnecesary: everything is games. For SEO reasons we want to remove this part, so, for example, this...

mysite.com/games/strategy/android

becomes this...

mysite.com/strategy/android

That is, a view with no fixed part in the path, just the parameters. How can I get this working?

Comment: If using the same view to drive the home page is an option you may be able to get away with changing the path to `<front>`

Comment: You can´t use <front> in a views path.

Answer (score 1):

You can go directly in your **View's settings**, in "Page settings" bloc, configure the **path** manually. Just remove the game part of the path.

**For your information:**

I suggest you to take a look at Pathauto module that allows you to define URL patterns very precisely for all the default pages of your site (but not views apparently): https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for
>   various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without
>   requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you
>   to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123.
>   The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which
>   the administrator can change.

Maybe it will be helpful for other cases.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the problem. The problem is that my URLS have more than one dimension, that is:

mysite.com/[taxonomy-genre]/[taxonomy-platform]

Comment: So you have 1 view per taxonomy-genre/taxonomy-platform? Are they built through the Views UI or in code?

Comment: Built on Views. I tried using Taxonomy Views to link the default taxonomy page to a view, so there are aliased URLs for the first parameter already:

misite.com/strategy/[parameter]

But this [parameter] doesn't reach the view, Drupal just gives me a 404.